# Filter on $geoNear (destination) and sort based on $geoNear( origin)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, geojson, geonear

I want to show the places for riders within a given distance and sort them based on origin points.

This is how the data looks like

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b5a9cd706f9b02068ebc4a6"), 
"name" : "Bangalore to hyderabad",
"locations" : [
    {
        "coordinates" : [
            77.5945627, 
            12.9715987
        ], 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5a9cd706f9b02068ebc4a8"), 
        "formattedAddress" : "Bengaluru, Karnataka, India", 
        "name" : "Bengaluru", 
        "type" : "Point", 
        "googlePlaceId" : "5b0d9fd719c9616d747b8a0d", 
        "placeType" : "origin" //***Sort by this***
    }, 
    {
        "coordinates" : [
            78.486671, 
            17.385044
        ], 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5a9cd706f9b02068ebc4a7"), 
        "formattedAddress" : "Hyderabad, Telangana, India", 
        "name" : "Hyderabad", 
        "type" : "Point", 
        "googlePlaceId" : "5b0d9fd719c9616d747b8a0d", 
        "locType" : "destination" // *****Filter by this***
    }
],
```

}

This is the homework I have done so far.

```
return await Ride.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 77.5946,12.8716 ] },
            distanceField: "distance",
            maxDistance: 20000000, //200Kms
            query: { private: false },
            spherical: true
        }
    },
    // { "$sort": { "distance": 1 } },
    { "$skip": 0 },
    { "$limit": 30 }
]);
```

This query filters the data based on all location points irrespective of locType.

2dsphere is index on location.coordinates

```
{ 
"v" : NumberInt(2), 
"key" : {
    "locations.coordinates" : "2dsphere"
}, 
"name" : "locations.coordinates_2dsphere", 
"ns" : "projectName.documentName", 
"background" : true, 
"2dsphereIndexVersion" : NumberInt(3)
```

}

Comment: Define better approach

Comment: is it the right way to approach for this problem?

Comment: On this site opinionated questions are off topic. You need to define "better" or "right" using objective, measurable terms.

Comment: true that, I reframed and removed the opinionated part. I am trying to achieve,  sort the location based on origin and filtered by radius of destination. Something like the answer to " show me list of trains which start near me and goes to 200KM around me"

Comment: So, you want to show locations within a limit (200 kilometres, for example) from a certain point, ordered ascendingly by distance of the given point?

Comment: No, There are 2 points, origin and destination of a trip. I want to show trips happening nearby a user. trips whom destination is within 200KM and origin point is near to them.

Comment: I understand the definition of the destination (d < 200KM), but I do not understand the definition of the source. Can you elaborate what "near" exactly means here?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the follow up man. I was able to solve my issue with a different approach to this problem. I fired geoNear query on origin point with a radius of 1000m and `query:{distance:{$lt:200}}`. I am saving the distance between origin and destination point initially at the inserting time. I will elaborate my answer properly by answering itself.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by a different approach.

First I added the distance field to my data. Made origin and destination as separate object instead of array.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b5a9cd706f9b02068ebc4a6"), 
"name" : "Bangalore to hyderabad",
"origin" : {
        "coordinates" : [
            77.5945627, 
            12.9715987
        ], 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5a9cd706f9b02068ebc4a8"), 
        "formattedAddress" : "Bengaluru, Karnataka, India", 
        "name" : "Bengaluru", 
        "type" : "Point", 
        "googlePlaceId" : "5b0d9fd719c9616d747b8a0d", 
    }, 
destination: {
        "coordinates" : [
            78.486671, 
            17.385044
        ], 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5a9cd706f9b02068ebc4a7"), 
        "formattedAddress" : "Hyderabad, Telangana, India", 
        "name" : "Hyderabad", 
        "type" : "Point", 
        "googlePlaceId" : "5b0d9fd719c9616d747b8a0d", 
    }
```

And then I made my query to fire geoNear on origin field with 1KM radius and query of distance less then 200KM.

```
Ride.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 77.5946,12.8716 ] },
            distanceField: "distanceFromOrigin",
            maxDistance: 1000, //1Km
            query: { private: false, distance:{$lt:200}},
            spherical: true
        }
    },
    // { "$sort": { "distanceFromOrigin":1,"distance": 1 } },
    { "$skip": 0 },
    { "$limit": 30 }
]);
```